# OSX Big Sur unable to install php 7.4 intl

Tags: php, macos-big-sur, intl

I am getting crazy since days as my new MacBook OS X Big Sur with php@7.4 is giving issues to XAMPP.

As far as I understood it's better to use the php from OS X than from XAMPP, but I am getting error while trying to install intl using brew. Here my code:

```
sudo pecl install intl
```

When I run the above I get this warning:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried:    /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/intl (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/intl, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/intl.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/intl.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/intl (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/intl, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/intl.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902/intl.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0
downloading intl-3.0.0.tgz ..
```

then I am asked about path for ICU.

```
Specify where ICU libraries and headers can be found [DEFAULT] :
```

I press ENTER and I get this:

```
running: /private/tmp/pear/temp/intl/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin/php-config --with-icu-dir=DEFAULT
```

Then the installation starts, but at the end I get this error:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (icu-uc >= 50.1 icu-io icu-i18n) were not met:

No package 'icu-uc' found
No package 'icu-io' found
No package 'icu-i18n' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables ICU_CFLAGS
and ICU_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/intl/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin/php-config --with-icu-dir=DEFAULT' failed
```

If I make:

```
which php
```

I get:

```
/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin/php
```

Anyone able to give real solution?

thanks!